# CSS dropdown not working in older IE browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have a CSS dropdown menu that works in most browsers, but not in some older versions of IE on XP. I wouldn't really care except many of my students still use this browser and therefore are limited in ability to use the site. On these older IE browsers, only the HOME link is displayed.

Here is the HTML followed by CSS. Can anyone figure out what is causing the problem?
Here are some Browser Stack screenshots: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/46848552eb08ea8bb0ca0b10c4843ed8cb6cfb3e

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="medial">
        <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="medial">
        <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/about/" title="About AnthonyTeacher.com">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="medial">
        <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/portfolio/" title="My Portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </li>
    <li class="medial"><a href="#" title="Course Homepages">COURSES</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/category/courses/2014s-liec/">Low Intermediate Conversation</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/category/courses/2014s-hiec/">High Intermediate Conversation</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/category/courses/2014s-elt/">ELT Practice</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/category/courses/2014s-tesol/">TESOL Practicum</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/oldercourses" title="View Previous Courses">Older Courses</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="medial"><a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/category/studentwork" title="Archive of work my students have done in my courses">STUDENT WORK</a>
    </li>
    <li class="medial"><?php add_thickbox(); ?>
<a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=4skddvl4euub3lj8qr88csf058%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Asia/Seoul?TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550" class="thickbox" title="View my course schedule">CALENDAR</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="mailto:anthony.teacher@yahoo.com">anthony.teacher@yahoo.com</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="smcf-link" href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/email-me/">Contact Form</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="social"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/anthony.teacherr" target="_blank" title="My Facebook Account for Students"><img src="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/wp-content/themes/blank2L/images/icons/Facebook.png" width="35px" alt="Facebook" /></a><a href="http://www.twitter.com/AnthonyTeacher" target="_blank" title="View my ELT-related Tweets"><img src="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/wp-content/themes/blank2L/images/icons/Twitter.png" width="35px" alt="Twitter" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/anthonyteacher" target="_blank" title="All my YouTube Videos"><img src="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/wp-content/themes/blank2L/images/icons/Youtube.png" width="35px" alt="YouTube" /></a><a href="http://lnkd.in/zkM8DU" target="_blank" title="See my LinkedIn Profile"><img src="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/wp-content/themes/blank2L/images/icons/Linkedin.png" width="35px" alt="LinkedIn" /></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* new menu */
#nav {
    background-image:url('http://www.anthonyteacher.com/wp-content/themes/blank2L/menubar.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    font: bold 12px arial;  
    width:100%;
    height: 29px;
}

/*Initialize*/
ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li.medial {
        background: url('http://www.anthonyteacher.com/wp-content/themes/blank2L/orangeborder1.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    background: #555555;
    color: #fff
}

/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;

}
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
        color: #000;
        font-weight:normal;
}
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
        color: #000;
        font-weight:normal;
        background-color: #ff0000;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
ul#menu li.social {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
ul#menu li.social a {
    margin: -11px -5px;
    }
ul#menu li.social a:hover {
     background: none;
    }
```

Comment: Early versions of IE do not understand hover on any element but <a> tags. You can download the necessary file from http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using something like [selectivizr.com](http://selectivizr.com/).

As @jeff has pointed out, early IE builds do not natively support `:hover` on anything other than `<a>`. Assuming your students have javascript turned on (unless they really are in the dark ages) Selectivizr should fix your problem without needing to change anything.